# Can't start vm because " Nonexistent host networking interface"

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

This is the whole error i get when trying to start vm with  **VBoxHeadless --startvm "omnitecvm" &** command

"**Error: failed to start machine. Error message: Nonexistent host networking interface, name 'enp0s3' (VERR_INTERNAL_ERROR)**
"

**What is my global goal:**
I'm moving one vm "vm1" to another pc "vm2", all by command line. Both vm are **ubuntu server**

**What have i tried:**
I've entered the "vm1" *.vbox file and copied the ***BridgedInterface name="Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller"*** line to the vm2 *.vbox file.

This doesn't work and i had the error so i entered "vm1" and did ***ifconfig*** to see name of the network interface, i noticed that it appears as "enp0s3" so i've copied that into the "vm2" *.vbox file.

Sadly this doesn't work too and i ran out of ideas

Comment: this is a common issue with cloned vms' There is a file /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules which has entries of the old interface / mac address.

Comment: @JohnGreenfield , I've just checked the *.rules file and the mac in vm1 is different that vm2